# How can I move slider in Katalon studio and the range starts from 619 to 1443

Tags: automated-testing, mobile-automation, katalon

I'm trying to change the slider value in Katalon, I tried using setSliderValue but I failed, Can anyone help me with this. I want to change the Slider value during runtime, Its 619 by default and I want it to increase by 100 for every iteration.

Can I set a variable to X value in properties and use it in the loop?

[image]

Comment: Please add your script code.

Comment: int x = 619

`TestObject dimming = new TestObject('Object Repository/Dimming/Brightness level 1')`

`dimming = dimming.addproperty("x",ConditionType.EQUALS, x+200)`

Comment: What happens when you run the script? Please copy and paste here execution log.